# Create connection to Oracle Autonomous Database from docker container via SqlAlchemy

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle18c

I am working on oracle cloud machine where python-flask application is deployed in docker container.
I am trying to initiate a connection from the application to Oracle Autonomous Database.
This connection is established by python ORM SQLAlchemy

The connection to mysql was established without any problem with details as given below.

```
engine = create_engine(
                'mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@host:3306/databasename')
            cls.session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            cls.base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
```

But when I am trying to connect to oracle database using cx_oracle driver its throwing an error.

```
engine = create_engine(
                'oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@host:1522/databasename')
            cls.session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            cls.base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
```

The error thrown is :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
```

From the above error I understood that I need to provide some oracle client library which i then downloaded and installed.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unzip
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/193000/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN unzip instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libaio1
RUN ldconfig
```

But issue still exists.

Has anyone tried to create a connection to Oracle Autonomous Database from a python application even if its not from docker container or even without sql-alchemy

**UPDATE**

Still facing this issue. I am pasting the exact dockerfile below for reference.

```
FROM python:3.6-buster
RUN echo 'setting workdir'
WORKDIR /app

RUN echo 'running docker, install dependencies of docker file '
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN echo 'now installing from req.txt if any left'
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN echo 'copying everything to app'
COPY . /app

RUN mkdir opt && cd opt && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/193000/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    echo /instantclient_19_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
    cd instantclient_19_3 && ls -lrt && ldconfig

ENV TNS_ADMIN=/app/keys
RUN ls -lrt
RUN echo 'port exposed'
EXPOSE 5060
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5060", "-t","120", "wsgi"]
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
```

Comment: For future readers, check the blog post [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Database through SQLAlchemy](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-database-through-sqlalchemy) and the cx_Oracle documentation [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autononmous Databases](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autononmous-databases).

Answer (score 3):

You missed one step of the Instant Client [install instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).  Before running `ldconfig` you need to update the library search path configuration so that Instant Client libraries are found.

Change the first path to the directory that you are unzipping the files into:

```
echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
```

Comment: @Jones updated dockerfile, still facing issue. can you help ?

Comment: Check out the Dockerfiles in this presentation https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1553560683840001mfXq/PF/DEV4626-Developing-and-Deploying-Python-and-Node.js-Applications-in-Docker_1568845042122001Vsfl.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jones for the great ppt, with its help I am able to solve my problem.
I am posting the complete dockerfile in case anyone else gets stuck too.

```
FROM python:3.7.4-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
WORKDIR /opt/oracle
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/193000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    rm -f instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN cd /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci
RUN echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig

RUN echo 'running docker, install dependencies of docker file '
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN echo 'now installing from req.txt if any left'
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN echo 'copying everything to app'
COPY . /opt/oracle

COPY /keys  /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/network/admin

RUN echo 'port exposed'
EXPOSE 5060
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5060", "-t","120", "wsgi"]
```

I have moved the keys folder within the application which has the wallet details of the oracle ADB. The requirements.txt file contains my dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Anyone else following the above should be careful about putting the wallet files into the container like this, because it means the keys are distributed and you have no control.  It is generally better to mount them with a Docker volume, as shown in the PPTX link.